# InfoPath use Web Service without a WSDL only by URL

Tags: asp.net, web-services, url, wsdl, infopath

I have a Web service from an ASP.NET application which I can access by URL, for example if I enter:

```
https://mycompany.com/MyApplication/UserDataService.aspx?Email=user.user@mycompany.com
```

I get xml data for the owner of the specified email. Which looks like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
- <userdata xmlns="">
-  <user account="w01\042">
    <ID>042</ID> 
    <email>user.user@mycompany.com</email> 
    <firstname>Chuck</firstname> 
    <lastname>Norris</lastname> 
    <phone>0445478452</phone> 
   </user>
  </userdata>
```

so basically I want to pass an email which I entered in InfoPath to the URL and retrieve the xml information, which I will display back in InfoPath. My problem is: InfoPath wants a URL with .../service.asmx?WSDL

Is there a workaround how I don't need WSDL or can I quickly create such a description file and paste it in the right folder afterwards? I've stumbled upon some WSDL generators. are they working fine?

cheers! phil